# Как правильно прочитать данные?

Tags: php

Вот что у меня получилось

```
$stmt = pdo()->prepare("SELECT * FROM `get_package_name` WHERE `name` = :name");
$stmt->execute();
$get = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

При попытке получить переменную get через print_r получаю ответ 1
Вот полный код

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SignIn</title>
</head>
<body>


<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/boot.php';

$user = null;

$get = null;

$stmt = pdo()->prepare("SELECT * FROM `get_package_name` WHERE `name` = :name");
$stmt->execute();
$get = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (check_auth()) {
    // Получим данные пользователя по сохранённому идентификатору
    $stmt = pdo()->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = :id");
    $stmt->execute(['id' => $_SESSION['user_id']]);
    $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
?>
<?php if ($user) { ?>

    <h1>Welcome <?=htmlspecialchars($user['login'])?>!</h1>  <?=($user['balance'])?>

    <form class="mt-5" method="post" action="do_logout">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Logout</button>
    </form>

<?php } else { ?>


<?php flash(); ?>

<? header('Location: login');
    die; ?>

<?php } ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Показывает просто белый экран если удалить

```
$stmt = pdo()->prepare("SELECT * FROM `get_package_name` WHERE `name` = :name");
$stmt->execute();
$get = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

то работает нормально

Comment: А это что за логика такая `'get' == $get`?

Comment: Сравнение я убрал оно там не нужно

Comment: И что теперь происходит?

Comment: Показывает белый экран

Comment: А как думаешь - плейсхолдер `:name` каким значением заменится?

Comment: значением name.

Comment: Если указываю $stmt->execute('name');  то через var_dump($get['name']); получаю NULL

Comment: То есть соседний `$stmt->execute(['id' => $_SESSION['user_id']]);` ни на какие мысли тебя не наводит?

Comment: Ну а причем тут получение данных пользователя если существует сессия до получения данных из совсем другой таблицы?

Comment: Ну может быть ты бы попробовал написать `$stmt->execute(['name' => 'some name']);` и посмотреть что выйдет.

Comment: Ну если я на прямую вставляю значение из бд то работает, но это же не правильно. `$stmt->execute(['name' => 'значение из бд']);`

Comment: Почему не правильно?

Comment: У меня в бд в таблице `get_package_name` есть столбец с названием `name` в нём одно значение `com.buratinoapps.faucet` если я вставляю это значение на прямую `$stmt->execute(['name' => 'com.buratinoapps.faucet']);` это не правильно, а если у меня будет там 100 или хотя бы несколько записей, мне что каждую запись напрямую вставлять?

Comment: Я не понимаю вопроса. Зачем вставлять каждую запись? Чего ты пытаешь добиться этим запросом? Если не надо фильтрации по имени, то делай запрос без where - `SELECT * FROM \`get_package_name\`` - вернутся все записи из таблицы.

Comment: В общем суть такова. На страницу будет приходить get запрос если то что приходит в запросе совпадает с тем что в бд то всё ок. Если использовать такой вариант как выше, то зачем мне вообще получать что то из бд если я могу сделать сравнение с условной переменной `$get='com.buratinoapps.faucet'; ` присвоив ей нужное мне значение?

Comment: То что пришло в гет-запросе - это переменная `$get`. Ее значение нужно передать в запрос. Сделать это можно так: `$stmt->execute(['name' => $get]);` запрос выполнится и найдет или не найдет пекедж с названием из переменной `$get`.

Comment: Не совсем. Всё что мне нужно `$stmt = pdo()->prepare("SELECT `name` FROM `get_package_name`");
$stmt->execute();
$get = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`